# Problemas em achar o erro!

Tags: javascript

Galera eu fiz um código e depois realizei um scanner e deu que o código deixa o site com uma brecha, não estou conseguindo encontrar onde esta o erro e se ele e grave ou não. Esse é o código:

```
var $K2 = jQuery.noConflict();

$K2(document).ready(function(){

  // Generic function to get URL params passed in .js script include
    function getUrlParams(targetScript, varName) {
        var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
        var scriptCount = scripts.length;
        for (var a = 0; a < scriptCount; a++) {
            var scriptSrc = scripts[a].src;
            if (scriptSrc.indexOf(targetScript) >= 0) {
                varName = varName.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
                var re = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + varName + "=([^&#]*)");
                var parsedVariables = re.exec(scriptSrc);
                if (parsedVariables !== null) {
                    return parsedVariables[1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Qual **brecha** ?

Comment: O Scanner, me alertou sobre uma possivel brecha que possibilita alguem invadir  o site atraves desse codigo, e tambem diz q o JQuery nao esta definido. eu queria ajuda pra saber se o codigo esta correto ou nao? Se precisa de alguns ajustes ou o Scanner me informou errado, infelizmente nao sei qual a brecha tambem, so a questao se o codigo esta correto.

Comment: Em relação do *jQuery* não estar definido, é porque falta importar ele: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: obrigado vlw mesmo

Comment: @wmsouza Marcou a resposta que nada tem a ver com a pergunta.

Comment: Que scanner usou? Qual a mensagem inteira de erro? Copia e cola tudo aqui, precisamos de detalhes.

Comment: Guilherme usei o Scanner Shadow Security Scanner. Primeiro ele me informa o script com erro com um link, diz q o erro esta na linha 9 cujo ea primeira linha do codigo que eu postei, tambem vem com caractere 1. ERRO:'jQuery' não esta definido Codigo: 800A1391 Origem: Erro em tempo de execuçao do Microsoft JScript. Essas sao as informaçoes que ele me passa

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No código que você postou falou um fechamento de chave **}** no fim do código pra encerrar a primeira função:

```js
var $K2 = jQuery.noConflict();

$K2(document).ready(function(){

  // Generic function to get URL params passed in .js script include
    function getUrlParams(targetScript, varName) {
        var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
        var scriptCount = scripts.length;
        for (var a = 0; a < scriptCount; a++) {
            var scriptSrc = scripts[a].src;
            if (scriptSrc.indexOf(targetScript) >= 0) {
                varName = varName.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
                var re = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + varName + "=([^&#]*)");
                var parsedVariables = re.exec(scriptSrc);
                if (parsedVariables !== null) {
                    return parsedVariables[1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}); // Faltou
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Amigo, quando for assim pergunte via comentário, talvez seja somente na pergunta que esteja faltando e no código real não.

Comment: o vlw pela resposta tbm

Comment: @dvd onde está errada, têm que ser mais claro amigo? Mas então quem marcou como correta? Você tem privilégio pra reverter a situação? Agradecido.
E pra constar faltava a chave sim.Deve ter sido um erro do solicitante.

Comment: falta `);` no após o `}`, claro que na pergunta também falta, mas por usar o stacksnippet para testar seria melhor adicionar

Comment: Obrigado @GuilhermeNascimento, não tinha notado. @dvd eu já tinha testado em 2 navegadores (Firefox e Opera) e não deu nenhum erro, coloquei várias TAGs com scripts puxados de outros sites e nenhum erro aconteceu, acredito que a brecha esteja em alguma script `listada` no HTML pela função. De resto o código funciona.